# Fadein/Fadeup effect using Bootstrap/CSS for a button over an image

Tags: html, css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to re-create this websites look as an exercise: `http://riotdesign.eu/en/`

I am struggling to be able to produce the button fadein/fadeup effect when one hovers over the images in the containers. I tried adding the

This is the code I have for the middle three(About, Portfolio, Contacts) sections are:

*Note I am using some embedded ruby as well besides bootstrap.

```
<div class="row index-row">


      <div class="col-sm-4 index-left">
        <div class="media-background">

          <div class="row index-row">
          <div class="media col-sm-5">
            <a class="pull-left" href="">
              <%= image_tag('computer.jpg', class: 'media-img', alt: 'About') %>
            </a>
          </div>
            <div class="media-body col-sm-7">
              <h4>
                <%= link_to 'About', root_path, class: 'media-heading' %>
              </h4>
            <p class="heading-text">
              "ABOUT What is Riot Design, our our clients and our specialties."
            </p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>




      <div class="col-sm-4 index-middle">
        <div class="media-background">

          <div class="row index-row">
          <div class="media col-sm-5">
            <a class="pull-left" href="">
              <%= image_tag('notebook.jpg', class: 'media-object', alt: 'Portfolio') %>
            </a>
          </div>
            <div class="media-body col-sm-7">
              <h4>
                <%= link_to 'Portfolio', root_path, class: 'media-heading' %>
              </h4>
            <p class="heading-text">
               PORTFOLIO Web design, app design, print works and photography.
            </p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-sm-4 index-right">
        <div class="media-background">

         <div class="row index-row">
          <div class="media col-sm-5">
            <a class="pull-left" href="">
              <%= image_tag('building.jpg', class: 'media-object', alt: 'Contacts', type: 'button') %>
            </a>
          </div>
            <div class="media-body col-sm-7">
              <h4>
                <%= link_to 'Contacts', root_path, class: 'media-heading' %>
              </h4>
            <p class="heading-text">
              Where to find the 
              <strong>Creatives</strong> 
              contact module and more.
            </p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
```

I tried adding something like this :

```
<div class="image-overlay">
  <a class="btn btn-default animated fadeInUp needsclick", href="#">Open</a>
</div>
```

And then adding some custom CSS i read about but could not figure it out. The button just shows up above the image rather than on top of it and does not fadein/fadeup like in the example website. Any ideas of what I can do to produce the effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/4RhhF/23/)**</kbd>

Basically use of

`transform`

`transition-timing-function`

`transition-duration`

`transition`

and its related cross browser properties
 `-webkit-transform` `-webkit-transition-timing-function` `-webkit-transition-duration` -`moz-transform` `-moz-transition-timing-function` `-moz-transition-duration` `-webkit-transition` etc

For more on it [**transform**](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/) **[transition](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)**

Your css for the same effect

```
.media-img .img-overlay {
    background: #363635;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 4;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  /* Firefox 4-15 */
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.50â€“12.00 */
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.lt-ie9 .media-img .img-overlay {
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}

.media .img-overlay a {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -24px;
}


.media:hover .img-overlay,
.media .media-img:hover .img-overlay {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  /* Firefox 4-15 */
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.50â€“12.00 */
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}


.media div.media-img img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2000ms;
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2000ms;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-duration: 2000ms;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.media:hover div.media-img img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1500ms;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1500ms;
    transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-duration: 1500ms;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}


.btn {
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;  /* Firefox 4-15 */
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.50â€“12.00 */
    transition: all 0.1s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}

.btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    color: #424b51;
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
}
```

SOme of them are used to override default bootstrap styles for button.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I will read more about it and report back! Thanks!